# Shellscript? Filter the output, inserting word at the end

Tags: shell

I'm trying to:

- get one line of the ps output
- to remove the back spaces
- to remove every word after the PrivateFrameworks/
- to add the word "bin/" front of PrivateFrameworks/
- to print the result

  IGOR:~ igor$ ps -e |grep PrivateFrameworks

  3857 ??         0:02.09 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/Resources/usbmuxd -launchd
   4046 ??         0:00.71 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Noticeboard.framework/Versions/A/Resources/nbagent.app/Contents/MacOS/nbagent
   4047 ??         0:00.05 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Noticeboard.framework/Versions/A/Resources/nbstated
   4324 ??         0:00.03 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/HelpData.framework/Versions/A/Resources/helpd
   4384 ??         0:00.13 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AOSKit.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/com.apple.iCloudHelper.xpc/Contents/MacOS/com.apple.iCloudHelper
   4621 ttys001    0:00.00 grep PrivateFrameworks

From this output, I expect the result /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/**bin**

I thought use sed, but I am completely lost

Comment: `s#PrivateFrameworks#PrivateFrameworks/bin#` what's the problem?

Comment: That's not at the end, though, it's in the middle.

Comment: StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), and we also [don't answer homework questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: ...well, "we don't answer homework questions" is a *little* too broad for SO -- they're allowed, but subject to the same quality bar as any other question (so it can't just be a restatement of an assignment, and needs to be a *specific* question about an *existing* implementation). [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/14122) is the canonical guidance -- but Barmar's link is a good one too. :)

Comment: Please show sed attempt so we can see where you are stuck?  As a tip, you do not need the grep at all.